# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findById')

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, postman

Hola a toda la comunidad, he decidido implementar una ruta de búsquedas dentro de mi API porque creo que resultaría útil. Mi problema ocurre cuando hago la llamada al endpoint desde postman, ahí es cuando el código del controlador crashea.

No estoy muy seguro del porqué del fallo y ya llevo un buen rato buscando la razón de del tipo de fallo que devuelve la consola pero no he sacado nada en claro.

El error en cuestión:

```
const usuarios = await Usuario.find({
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
    at buscarUsuarios (C:\Users\xniko\Desktop\Cursos Udemy\Curso Node\07-REST-server\controllers\buscar.controller.js:26:36)
```

> Da el fallo con todos los .find y .findById

A continuación os facilito el código de los dos archivos en cuestión.

**buscar.js**

```
const {Router} = require ('express');
const {buscar}= require('../controllers/buscar.controller')

const router = Router();

router.get('/:coleccion/:termino',buscar)




module.exports=router;
```

**buscar.controller.js**

```
const { response } = require("express");
const { isValidObjectId } = require("mongoose");

const { Usuario, Categoria, Producto } = require('../models');

const coleccionesPermitidas=[
    'usuarios',
    'categorias',
    'productos',
    'roles'
]

const buscarUsuarios = async(termino='',res = response)=>{

    const esMongoID = isValidObjectId(termino);

    if (esMongoID) {
        const usuario = await Usuario.findById(termino);
        return res.json({
            results:(usuario)?[usuario]:[]
        });
    }

    const regex = new RegExp( termino,'i');

    const usuarios = await Usuario.find({
        $or: [{nombre:regex},{correo:regex}],
        $and: [{estado:true}]
    });

    res.json({
        results:usuarios
    })

}

const buscarCategorias = async(termino='',res = response)=>{

    const esMongoID = isValidObjectId(termino);

    if (esMongoID) {
        const categoria = await Categoria.findById(termino);
        return res.json({
            results:(categoria)?[categoria]:[]
        });
    }

    const regex = new RegExp( termino,'i');

    const categorias = await Categoria.find({
        $or: [{nombre:regex}],
        $and: [{estado:true}]
    });

    res.json({
        results:categorias
    })

}

const buscarProductos = async(termino='',res = response)=>{

    const esMongoID = isValidObjectId(termino);

    if ( esMongoID ) {
        const producto = await Producto.findById(termino)
                            .populate('categoria','nombre');
        return res.json({
            results: ( producto ) ? [ producto ] : []
        });
    }

    const regex = new RegExp( termino,'i');

    const productos = await Producto.find({
        $or: [{nombre:regex}],
        $and: [{estado:true}]
    });

    res.json({
        results:productos
    })

}

const buscar = (req,res=response)=>{

    const {coleccion,termino} = req.params

    if (!coleccionesPermitidas.includes(coleccion)) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            msg:`Las colecciones permitidas son: ${coleccionesPermitidas}`
        })
    }

    switch (coleccion) {
        
        case 'usuarios':
        buscarUsuarios(termino,res);
        break;
        case 'categorias':
        buscarCategorias(termino,res);
        break;
        case 'productos':
        buscarProductos(termino,res);
        break;

        default:
            res.status(500).json({
                msg:'Busqueda sin implementar'
            })
    }
}



module.exports={buscar}
```

> Hago mis peticiones http a un url como el siguiente => http://localhost:(puerto)/api/buscar/:coleccion/:termino

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Aprender inglés para programar es realmente importante... tu mensaje del error te está diciendo exactamente cual es el problema. No se puede ejecutar el método `find` porque `undefined` no tiene el método `find()`. Es decir, tu variable `Usuario` está sin asignar. Algo mal estás haciendo en el export/import.

Comment: Me alegra poder decirte que hasta el día de hoy sé traducir sin ningún problema, pero en el resto de mis controladores uso de la misma manera las importaciones y no me dan este error.

Comment: *en el resto de mis controladores uso de la misma manera las importaciones y no me dan este error* -> Nosotros no vemos el resto de tus controladores. Solo vemos lo que pones en la pregunta y juzgamos con la información que aportas. Si la pregunta está incompleta, cómo vamos a poder ayudarte de manera correcta? Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deberían de aportar **SIEMPRE** un [mre]. Un trozo de código que podamos copiar, pegar y reproducir personalmente el error si no, a no ser que veamos algo muy obvio, solo podemos intuir y adivinar... y eso no es manera de responder.

Comment: No veo el objeto `Usuario` en el código de tu pregunta. Sólo veo que haces `const { Usuario, ... } = require '../models';`. Por favor agrega lo que tengas en el fichero `models.js` o en la ruta `../models` (suponiendo que es una ruta con diferentes achivos). Saludos

Comment: Eso se debe a que dentro de la carpeta de models tengo un archivo llamado index.js, en el cual se referencian los otros archivos, cuando haces la ruta de ese modo nodejs busca un index dentro del directorio de forma automática. Esto nos ayuda a tener importaciones más claras y concisas a mi parecer